# how to manipulate onchange ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form where when I select the select option in the input (jurusan) it is also filled in based on the value. Here I want to change the value of the value obtained by selecting the option, how do I do it?

Suppose I select select A will appear 1

So how do you change the number 1 to another value? suppose I want to turn it into a car.

```html
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Latihan Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Latihan Ajax 1</h2>

    <select id="nama" name="fakultas" onchange="fakultas()">
        <option value="0">-Pilih-</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>
        <option value="4">D</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="jurusan" id="jurusan">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fakultas(){
            var data = document.getElementById("nama").value;
            document.getElementById("jurusan").value = data;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can make value anything you want.  It doesn't have to be a number

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  The title mentions AJAX but I see no AJAX call in your code.  Please edit your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you are already setting the value in your function and as another commenter pointed out you can change that value to anything you wish. In the snippit below, I use an array to show you how you can use the ***options*** ***value*** => ***a number***, which could represent an ***index*** for the **array**, to get the ***value*** of the **array**.

```js
const camaros = ['Choose', 'Camaro RS', 'Camaro SS', 'Camaro SS 1LE', 'Camaro ZL1']

function fakultas() {
  var data = document.getElementById("nama").value;
  document.getElementById("jurusan").value = camaros[data];
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Latihan Ajax</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Latihan Ajax 1</h2>

  <select id="nama" name="fakultas" onchange="fakultas()">
    <option value="0">-Pilih-</option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="jurusan" id="jurusan">

</body>

</html>
```

You could also use an ***array*** of ***objects*** that use words as keys to retrieve a ***value*** with that *key* and then set the inputs ***value***.

```js
const obj = [{
  car: 'Devel Sixteen',
  boat: 'Westinghouse J34',
  plane: 'X-15',
  spaceship: 'Millennium Falcon'
}]




function fakultas() {
  var data = document.getElementById("nama").value;
  document.getElementById("jurusan").value = obj[0][data];
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Latihan Ajax</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Latihan Ajax 1</h2>

  <select id="nama" name="fakultas" onchange="fakultas()">
    <option value="">-Pilih-</option>
    <option value="car">A</option>
    <option value="boat">B</option>
    <option value="plane">C</option>
    <option value="spaceship">D</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" name="jurusan" id="jurusan">

</body>

</html>
```